# Android Compose 1.1.0 with Kotlin 1.6.10 bug?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have updated my project to Kotlin 1.6.10, Compose 1.1.0 and compose compiler to 1.1.0

Previously I was using Kotlin 1.5.31, Compose 1.0.5 and compose compiler 1.0.5, and it running ok

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Test() {
    var value: String? = null
    Scaffold(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), backgroundColor = Color.White) {
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            val ret = value?.let {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(50.dp)
                        .background(color = Color.Red)
                )
            }
            ret ?: Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))
            Text(text = "ret = $ret")
            Text(text = "KotlinVersion = ${KotlinVersion.CURRENT}")
        }
    }
}
```

The above Spacer function has never been executed

look this:
[Test Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz9sl.png)

At first I thought it was an issue with Kotlin 1.6.10

[Kotlin 1.6.10 Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alDDg.png)

[Kotlin 1.6.10 Small Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cqqB.png)

After check out the official documentation and run small test. I don't think it's a issue with Kotlin 1.6.10

So is this a bug in Compose 1.1.0?

Comment: yes, this is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198511576)

Comment: Ohhhhhh, Thank you for answering my doubts

Comment: what is the fix?